# How to add substring range in Flutter if the word is less than the range | Flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart, range

```
Text('simply dummy text for printing '.substring(0, 12),),
```

i want to print a text from a range 0 to 12 characters. From the above code it works fine if it has more than 12 characters. But if it is less than 12 characters it gives the error value not in range:12. How to print the whole line if the character is less than 12 without showing the range error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the string length is greater than 12 before calling substring.

You could do:

```
var text = 'simply dummy text for printing ';
Text(text.length > 12 ? text.substring(0, 12) : text,),
```

Answer (score 4):

You can combine [substring](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/String/substring.html) and [clamp](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/num/clamp.html) methods:

```
void main() {
  print('123456789012'.take(8)); // 12345678
  print('123456'.take(8)); // 123456
}

extension StringX on String {
  String take(int nbChars) => substring(0, nbChars.clamp(0, length));
}
```